# No trusted certificate found while certificates are in cacerts

Tags: java, ssl

From a Java client I am posting data to a HTTPS address. For this address I have added the SSL certificates + intermediate into the java cacerts security. It worked for a long time. Suddenly my java client does not work any more and I get this error:

```
error message: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: com.ibm.jsse2.util.j: No trusted certificate found
```

The SSL certificate is still the same, the only difference which I see is that the root certificate changed names (from Comodo to Sectigo). I also downloaded all Sectigos intermediates from: https://support.sectigo.com/Com_KnowledgeDetailPage?Id=kA01N000000rfBO

and have also put this inside the cacerts but still I get a No trusted certificate found, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: How should the leaf of your certificate chain still be valid if the root CA changes? If the root CA changes, *all* children are invalid!

Comment: I downloaded all the new certificates again and put it into the cacerts but still the same problem.

Comment: You replaced just the intermediate certs and not all of them?

Comment: Use >keytool -list -v -keystore cacerts command to view certificates registered

Comment: I did three things : 1. I copied the certificates from the browser (child and intermediate and root) created a base64 cer file and inserted those into cacerts 2. I went to Comodo website and downloaded intermediate CA files 3. I went to Sectigo website and also downloaded intermediate CA files and I have put all points into cacerts

Comment: Also, if you add the concrete certificate of the HTTPS endpoint to your cert store, you wouldn't need the CA as you already trust the actual server.

Comment: Just a wild guess from my side, make sure JRE you are querying and using are same

Comment: Seems that I still have the same problem.